# How can I cross-validate by Pytorch and Optuna

Tags: pytorch, optuna

I want to use cross-validation against the official Optuna and pytorch-based sample code (https://github.com/optuna/optuna/blob/master/examples/pytorch_simple.py).

I thought about splitting the data for cross-validation and trying parameter tuning for each fold, but it seems that the average accuracy of each parameter cannot be obtained because the parameters that can be checked in study.trials_dataframe() are different each time.

Comment: Short answer: Optuna's Bayesian process is what cross-validation attempts to approximate. Check out this answer and comment there if possible; I see no need to cross-post at this time: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/491268/272731

Answer (score 10):

I think we need to evaluate all folds and calculate the mean inside an objective function. I create an [example notebook](https://meet.google.com/linkredirect?authuser=0&dest=https%3A%2F%2Fcolab.research.google.com%2Fdrive%2F1wCQw3NTad2S4kXxxAqN0WjORhiqyVV2v%3Fusp%3Dsharing), so please take a look.

In the notebook, I slightly modified the `objective` function to pass the dataset with the arguments and added a wrapper function `objective_cv` to call the `objective` function with the split dataset. Then, I optimized the `objective_cv` instead of the `objective` function.

```python
def objective(trial, train_loader, valid_loader):

    # Remove the following line.
    # train_loader, valid_loader = get_mnist()

    ...

    return accuracy


def objective_cv(trial):

    # Get the MNIST dataset.
    dataset = datasets.MNIST(DIR, train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

    fold = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    scores = []
    for fold_idx, (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(fold.split(range(len(dataset)))):
        train_data = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, train_idx)
        valid_data = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, valid_idx)

        train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
            train_data,
            batch_size=BATCHSIZE,
            shuffle=True,
        )
        valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
            valid_data,
            batch_size=BATCHSIZE,
            shuffle=True,
        )

        accuracy = objective(trial, train_loader, valid_loader)
        scores.append(accuracy)
    return np.mean(scores)


study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
study.optimize(objective_cv, n_trials=20, timeout=600)
```

Comment: A great solution for CV!

Comment: What do you think about using SuccessiveHalvingPruner like here? https://medium.com/@walter_sperat/using-optuna-with-sklearn-the-right-way-part-3-3a072f97dca4